# Send e-mail from outlook to a group with Powershell

Tags: powershell

Everyday when the "breakfast-service" arrives at our Office, the receptionist sends an e-mail to the whole office. Those email-addresses are saved in a Group. The e-mails are sent via outlook.

Now I have the task, to create a powershell script, that does the same, but I don't know how to send an e-mail to the group?

```
Start-Process Outlook
$Outlook = New-Object -com Outlook.Application
$mail = $Outlook.CreateItem(0)
$mail.importance = 2
$mail.subject = “[Text]“
$mail.body = “[Text]“
$mail.To = “[This is where the group should be]“
$mail.Send()
```

Comment: Does that group have a server-side entity?

Comment: Yes, the group has a server-side entity.

Comment: If so, you can derive its primary SMTP address from recipient and stuff it here. Problem solved.

Comment: Do you get any error message or denial message from the server when you try to email the group? In what way specifically are you not able to mail the group?

Comment: Since my boss, doesn't wan't to install a snippet on the receptionists computer, I have to enter all the names. Thank you anyways for your answers!

Comment: Check the Outlook Address Book, find the 'email group' and have a look at its properties. You will see an email address similar to `GroupName@company.com`. This is the Groups email address, anything sent to this email address will be delivered to everyone in the Group. There's no need to install anything to use this email address, just use it like this: `$mail.To = "GroupName@company.com"`

Comment: If the group has an ActiveDirectory entry as a distribution group, `(Get-ADGroup -Identity $Groupname -Properties *).mail` will return the information sought in @JamesC. 's comment.

Comment: Ah yes, it works with the E-Mail address of the group. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the Outlook Address Book, find the 'email group' and have a look at its properties. You will see an email address similar to `GroupName@company.com`.

This is the Groups email address, anything sent to this email address will be delivered to everyone in the Group. There's no need to install anything to use this email address, just use it like this:

```
Start-Process Outlook
$Outlook = New-Object -com Outlook.Application
$mail = $Outlook.CreateItem(0)
$mail.importance = 2
$mail.subject = “[Text]“
$mail.body = “[Text]“
$mail.To = "GroupName@company.com"
$mail.Send()
```